# Images and animated transformation

Tags: .net, image-processing

For images static transformations it is the AForge framework developed, but what to use if I need dynamic (animated) transormation?

For example: I have a picture and I need to make some its part to become brighter, not instantly but with animation, from current state to expected value for some period of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested - I found 2 solutions:

1. Modify in the runtime and swap images
2. (The one I've chosen) Move to WPF